# Construir string com caracteres especiais

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itextsharp, ascii

Estou a construir PDF's, e preciso de imprimir uma string com caracteres especiais. Para tal estou a construir a string da seguinte forma (usando `iTextSharp`):

```
PdfPCell teste = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("<O meu texto> '\u20ac'", fontetexto));
```

Agora o que importa, a minha string é `"<O meu texto> '\u20ac'"`, onde o `'\u20ac'` apresenta `€`. Só que eu quero imprimir um ponto tipo password, como a seguinte imagem apresenta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ando farto de procurar listas com caracteres especiais para C# / ASP MVC e não encontro mais do caracteres como `/ , [, ]` por exemplo. Como é que posso construir a string com os caracteres especiais?

Comment: [Tabela de caracteres Unicode](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) Talvez ajude.

Comment: Estive à procura do `\u20ac` e não o encontrei

Comment: Linha 20A0 + Coluna 0C = 20AC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Talvez seja melhor reformular seu código

Dê uma olhada nessa classe:

```
iTextSharp.text.ListItem
```

Com ela você tem exatamente o que deseja.

Veja o exemplo:

```
it.List list = new it.List(it.List.UNORDERED, 10f);
list.SetListSymbol("\u2022");
list.IndentationLeft = 30f;
list.Add(new it.ListItem("One"));
list.Add("Two");
list.Add("Three");
list.Add("Four");
list.Add("Five");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
PdfPCell teste = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("<O meu texto>" + ((char)0x20AC).ToString(), fontetexto));
```

**Edit**

O caracter especial desse ponto que você quer é `U+25CF`, ou seja:

```
PdfPCell teste = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(((char)0x25CF).ToString() + " <O meu texto>", fontetexto));
```

Comment: A minha dúvida é como colocar um ponto tipo password, a string consigo construir

Comment: @CesarMiguel Veja a resposta editada.

Comment: Onde é que consultou o código? Dava imenso jeito :P

Comment: continua sem apresentar

Comment: Aí depende da fonte que você está usando, se ela apresenta o caracter especial. Nem todas as fontes possuem.

Comment: Já consegui com o exemplo do @2madera. Obrigado na mesma, apesar de não ter conseguido parece resposta válida!

Answer (score 1):

### Uma String nada mais é que um Array de Char:

```
char[] caracteres = {'0x20AC', '0x20AC', '0x20AC'};
string palavra = new string(caracteres);
```

Comment: A minha dúvida é como colocar um ponto tipo password, a string consigo construir